# Issue with google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize")

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Thanks for checking it out.. I have an issue with this .js were i am using jquery to resize the map-canvas div. But once it has been resized i need the actual google map to reset its boundaries which i am using google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize"), here is my code but once it fires the resize of the div, it cannot run the resize map trigger due to it being undefined? here is my .js

```
// JavaScript Document

// Scripts below in regards to instantiating the google map.
var map;

function initialize() {

var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.1840517,150.7131903);
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 17,
    center: myLatLng,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT
    }

};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: '6 Station Street, Douglas Park, 2569' 
});

var contentString = '<div id="mapContent">'+'TESTING'+'</div>';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
});

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

$(function() {

    $("#expand-map").click(function() {
        $("#map-canvas").animate({"height" : "800px"}, 500);
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    });
```

});

Comment: I believe there is an issue with scope but i do not know how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have just call the initialize function to draw map again after the `map-canvas` dimensions changed in `animate` function callback.

```
$(function() {
    $("#expand-map").click(function() {
        $("#map-canvas").animate({"height" : "800px"}, 500,function(){
            initialize();
        });

    });
});
```

see here:
`demo` [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lokeshpahal/2MNnH/2/)

Comment: This is a good option that works, but perhaps if a user was scrolling around the map already. once they expand the map it would reset them back to the original origin. Which i believe is a little bit of a pain.

Comment: in this case just trigger the map `resize` event instead of draw map again `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` see here: http://jsfiddle.net/lokeshpahal/2MNnH/6/

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, i used the jsfiddle above to get mine working.

Comment: pleasure to help you :)